# Excel if and or statement

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, excel-2010

EXCEL: Need help creating a formula that will return a true/false statement. I was thinking of using the IF/IFERROR(SEARCH) statement

Checking row to see if these conditions are true or false.

Conditions: Contains word: "yellow"

OR contains 8 number string AND 8 number string does not begin with the letter "B"

Comment: Can you show us your data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below formula-

```
=OR(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Yellow",A1)),AND(LEN(A1)=8,LEFT(A1,1)<>"B"))
```

[image]